# Grid not display proper string

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, grid

I am trying to display string on grid column but grid not displaying properly or full string on grid .
String contain some special characters and normal and enter key in that string and grid only accept string before the enter key and skip after the enter key whole string.

Expecting that grid will disply string after enter key in the string
Example: hi "enter key press here "
Hello
So grid will display "hi hello" but is displaying only "hi"

Comment: Are you sure that it's only displaying the first line or is it just that you can't see the second line because the row isn't tall enough?

Comment: Also, I would expect that you'd have to set the `CellStyle.WrapMode` property of the column to `True` to make it wrap. I'm still not sure what that would mean for editing, because the editing control would be a standard `TextBox` and that only supports a single line. I suspect that you'd have to handle the `EditingControlShowing` event and set the `Multiline` property of the editi8ng control to `True`. I haven't got time to test that right now though.